# What is the proper way to measure the cut-out for the kitchen range?

Tags: kitchens, range

I want to upgrade my kitchen range. I currently have an old 1987 kenmore drop-in. The manual lists it as a "30 inch drop-in", but when I lift up the cooking surface, the distance from counter top to counter top is about 29.5 inches (give or take a few cm). I spoke with several appliance retailers and I get varying answers. Some say that the cut-out should be slightly less than 30, others say they won't install unless it is 30 or more. Which is it? Also, I want to upgrade to an induction cooktop. The circuit breaker for the stove is rated for 50 amps, but my old stove is only 20 amps so I don't know if they installed the proper gauge of wiring for 50 amps or cut corners and used wire that was rated for 20 amps.

Comment: When you say a drop-in do you mean a cook-top with four heating elements, but with no oven underneath?

Comment: Drop-in meaning that the range does not sit on the floor, there is a toe-kick panel beneath the oven that runs the entire length of the cabinets

Comment: So there are four surface heating elements and an oven, and all this worked on a 20-A breaker? I am surprised. Is the oven self-cleaning? I think the manual of our modest GE range (but self cleaning) calls for a 40-A breaker, but the original builder's range had four burners, plus two ovens and an exhaust fan and I suppose that is why the original wiring and breaker was 50 A. We now have one oven and the exhaust fan is on a separate 120 V circuit.

Comment: The circuit breaker for the stove has a "50" stamped on the switch, so I assume that means it's a 50 amp fuse, but the stove itself is only a 20 amp stove. I wanted to know if it was standard code to have to use a wire gauge that can withstand 50 amps with a 50 amp breaker, or if maybe the could have cut corners and used a wire meant for 20 amps and just used a 50 amp breaker.

Comment: The purpose of the breaker is to protect the house wiring. It would be a code violation and a huge breach of professional ethics for an electrician to put a 50-A breaker on a circuit with wire that is only rated for 20 A. I think you can assume that your wiring is rated for 50-A, unless you have evidence to the contrary. That is, if you want to put a range on this circuit that requires a 40-A or a 50-A breaker, you are not required to to verify that the wire is of sufficient size. But if this is wired directly in a box then you could measure the size of the conductor at the time of connection.

Comment: Is the old range electric or natural gas/propane?

Comment: it is electric. i'm starting to believe the amperage is incorrect, i had to look up a manual for this model since it is so old and I believe the amperage is for the gas version of this stove, i have the electric

Comment: this is puzzling: "29.5 inches (give or take a few cm)" I don't know why you are mixing units but a cm is about 3/8 inch, so its like saying give or take an inch..

Answer (score 1):

Typically a "drop-in" range will rest on the adjoining counter top surfaces.
That the actual cabinet is narrower, gives you the wiggle room you need to drop in the unit to install it.

If you want to change to a cooktop installation, that is something that is only supported by the counter top, then you'll need to build a cabinet, and provide a counter top with cutout to fill that space.

In any case, as others have suggested, check the exact measurements of any product that you select.  In this age of the internet, most manufacturers have their Installation Guides online, you can pull a copy in spite of the retail staff.

Answer (score 0):

There should be fairly standard dimensions for this type of thing but the best advice is to carefully measure the existing cutout and then take that information with you when you shop for a new unit. There may very well be unit to unit differences that will need to be taken into account. One factor to consider is how much of a hanging flange the new unit has. Often the width of the flange can accommodate a range of cutout width.

Also you should evaluate how the existing cutout is situated in the cabinet and what type of counter top there is. Sometimes it is totally possible to widen a cutout gap of 29.5 inches out to 30 inches if the cabinet sides below are wider apart than 29.5 inches. Of course you would only do that if needed but do know that widening may be all from one side or could be some from each side.

As far as the electrical wiring goes the cable jacket should have marking along it that shows the gauge of the wire. You can then determine the ampacity from the size of the wire. If you are at all uncomfortable with working with the electrical wiring the best advice is to hire a professional electrician.

Answer (score 0):

The cutout in our soapstone counter is 30 3/8" wide. We have a GE slide-in electric range with single oven that is exactly 30" wide with an overhang on top of 3/8" on each side.

The range circuit is protected by the original GE 50-A 240-V double-pole breaker, now 47 years old. The range is connected with a cord and plugs into a 4-wire receptacle. The wire is some very thick stranded aluminum, not sure about the exact gauge.

Comment: One house we lived in 38 years ago had a drop in cook-top with a cabinet underneath. There were two ovens located elsewhere in the kitchen. It could be that the dimensions for a '30 inch' cook-top are different than those for a slide-in range or a free-standing range with integral oven.

Comment: The model that I am interested in shows that the cooktop surface is 30 inches, but the width of the actual appliance is only 29 and 7/8 inches. I am very confused. I would think that I only need the 29 and 7/8 inches for the cutout if that is the case. May I ask if your GE range had any "wiggle room" between your cabinets?

Comment: In our current house there is very little wiggle room, ca 3/16" on each side or 3/8" total. The cook-top is 30 3/4" wide so it overlaps the counter top on each side.

Comment: In your case if the appliance is 29 7/8" I suppose that a small gap between the sides of the appliance and the cabinet is necessary to prevent heating of the combustible wooden cabinetry. I would think that the width of the drop-in cook top would have to be about 3/4" more than the width of the opening since the entire appliance is suspended from the top.

Comment: I see that for a certain GE drop-in the opening width must be 29 15/16" minimum and 30 1/16" maximum. Looks like the drop in has a tighter specification than for a slide in, but *maybe* the one you want would fit in your opening.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant when you wrote " the stove itself is only a 20 amp stove". Is this at 240 V? How is the present stove connected--hard wired or through a plug into a receptacle?

Comment: the stove is probably rated for 40 amps. I had to look up the manual online and the title was "kenmore electric\gas range" and I think it listed values only for the gas version. I believe it is hardwired, but I do not know since it is a drop in stove

Answer (score 0):

The 30" specified in the description of appliances is due to standard cabinet sizes 12" 18" 24" 30" 36" 48".  It does not mean the unit is that size exactly, in all cases the nominal and maximum size of hole in countertop is specified in the installation instructions.  Be warned these sizes can range wildly between brands.  Always double check install sizes required for any appliances in the manual before purchase.  It will save you headaches later☺